# How to use single Resharper setting file by multiple users

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I am looking for a way to create a single Resharper setting file and share it with my team members, and if in the future I want to make a change in that file then that setting should automatically be applied to the rest of the team members.

Kind Regards

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Sharing_Configuration_Options.html You manage this by keeping the settings under source control, and they will be automatically applied when the latest version is fetched.

Comment: This will not solve my problem, for example, I have 10 solutions then I have to copy the same file and push with each individual solution, but then If I want to make a change in a file then I have to push the change for each solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's something we were facing in our team as well. Here's what we did:

- Repo `CodeStyling`

  - Contains `Shared.DotSettings`
- Repo `App1`

  - Solution `App1.sln.DotSettings` (which is under source control as well) has the following entry:
    `<s:String x:Key="/Default/Environment/InjectedLayers/FileInjectedLayer/=15C315CEAAF9FC4EA4785B81F2986594/RelativePath/@EntryValue">..\CodeStyling\Shared.DotSettings</s:String>`

So every repo references `Shared.DotSettings`. Of course the usage of relative file paths has some implications on the directory structure, but this is a price we're willing to pay.
Just be careful when adding this reference: when I introduced this pattern (maybe one year ago), Rider was putting absolute paths into `App1.sln.DotSettings`. I had to convert them manually to relative paths, which works like a charm.

In your case all of your 10 solutions would have to add this reference.